# Formset shows invalid when updating the form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Can anyone help me why my formset is showing invalid when trying to update the form. It works perfectly when creating the form. The normal form is editing but the formset is not.

`def content_edit_view(request, id):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, id=id)
    LectureFormset = modelformset_factory(Lecture, fields=('lecture_title', 'lecture_content', 'youtube_url'), extra=0)

```
if course.user != request.user:
    raise Http404()

if request.method == 'POST':
    content_edit_form = ContentEditForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=course)
    formset = LectureFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if content_edit_form.is_valid(): 
        content_edit_form.save()
        data = Lecture.objects.filter(course=course)

        # give index of the item for a formset item strting form 0 and (f)the item itself 
        if formset.is_valid():
            for index, f in enumerate(formset):
                if f.cleaned_data:
                    if f.cleaned_data['id'] is None:
                        video = Lecture(course=course, lecture_title=f.cleaned_data.get('lecture_title'), lecture_content=f.cleaned_data.get('lecture_content'), youtube_url=f.cleaned_data.get('youtube_url'))
                        video.save()
                    else:
                        video = Lecture(course=course, lecture_title=f.cleaned_data.get('lecture_title'), lecture_content=f.cleaned_data.get('lecture_content'), youtube_url=f.cleaned_data.get('youtube_url'))              
                        d = Lecture.objects.get(id=data[index].id) #get slide id which was uploaded
                        d.lecture_title = video.lecture_title # changing the database tiitle with new title
                        d.lecture_content = video.lecture_content #changing the database content with new content
                        d.youtube_url = video.youtube_url # changing the database content with new content
                        d.save()

            return redirect('teacher-profile')

        else:
            print('formset is invalid')

    else:
        print("form is invalid")

else:
    content_edit_form = ContentEditForm(instance=course)
    formset = LectureFormset(queryset=Lecture.objects.filter(course=course))

context = {
    'contentForm': content_edit_form,
    'course': course,
    'formset': formset,
}


return render(request, 'apps/contentEdit.html', context)`
```

Comment: Check `formset.errors` and `formset.non_form_errors` to see what the errors are.

Comment: @Alasdair i did it and got the error stating the id field is required for the formset but i am getting the id

Comment: It sounds like you are missing `{{ form.id }}` in your template when you loop through the formset.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you sir, i added {{ form.id }} in template and now it is updating

Comment: This question and its resolution seem very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59863039/4107809